# Is there a way to save referenced information on referenced firleds from another table as String fields?

Tags: web2py

I have 2 tables one table references the other table.

```
db.define_table('store_registration',
                Field('first_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('last_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('contact_number', label=SPAN('Cell Number'), requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('id_number', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('program', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('level_is', label=SPAN('Level'), requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('module_is', label=SPAN('Module'), requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('branch', label=SPAN('Branch'), requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('residential_place', label=SPAN('Residence'), requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('region', 'reference auth_group', default=get_group(), writable=False), #*Here*
                Field('recorded_by', 'reference auth_user', default=auth.user_id, writable=False),
                format="%(first_name)s %(last_name)s"
               )

db.define_table('temperatures',
                Field('employee', 'reference store_registration', writable=False),
                Field('branch', 'reference store_registration', writable=False),
                Field('temperature', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('ID_No', 'reference store_registration', writable=False),
                Field('Cell_No', 'reference store_registration', writable=False),
                Field('residential', 'reference store_registration', writable=False))
```

I am trying to have the referenced fields pre-populated with their default values in a table form in my function so that I don't have to populate them manually like this:

```
def client_details():
    details=db.store_registration(request.args(0, cast=int))
    db.temperatures.employee.default=details.id #Works correctly
    db.temperatures.ID_No.default=details.id_number
    db.temperatures.Cell_No.default=details.contact_number
    db.temperatures.branch.default=details.branch
    db.temperatures.residential.default=details.residential_place
    form=SQLFORM(db.temperatures)
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash=T('Temp Recorded')
    return locals()
```

But this gives me an error:

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'> invalid literal for long() with base 10:
```

I read somewhere that this occurs because

> reference fields are intended to store the integer record ID's of the
>   referenced records, not copies of string fields from referenced
>   records.

Is there a way I can achieve my above task without causing this error?!

Regards;

Answer (score 0):

The fields in db.temperatures should not be 'reference store_registration'.  That's only valid if they're foreign keys pointing to db.store_registration.id